# XML Objectifier returning XML string rather than JSON object

Tags: jquery, xml, json

I am trying to use XML Objectifier (x2j.js from http://www.terracoder.com/index.php/xml-objectifier) to convert some XML to JSON. I have a very simple test case where x2j.js is returning a string of XML rather than a JSON object. Since XML Objectifier seems to be used on many production sites, I assume I'm the one making a mistake.

Both jQuery and x2j.js are included with  tags before this code:

```
var xmlstring = '<results><configuration><user>Balay</user></configuration></results>';
var xmldoc = $.textToXML(xmlstring);
console.log(xmldoc);
var jsondata = $.xmlToJSON(xmlstring);
console.log("jsondata = " + jsondata);
```

The call to $.textToXML is working -- Firebug shows an XML document that I can drill down into. But after the call to $.xmlToJSON, printing jsondata to the console just shows the original XML string.

I'm sure this is newbie user error, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

`var jsondata = $.xmlToJSON(xmlstring);`

Youre using it on the xml string... it should be:

`var jsondata = $.xmlToJSON(xmldoc);`

Comment: It doesn't work that way, either. I put in the call to $.textToXML to be sure that I had the basic syntax right, but it should be unnecessary.

Comment: @Erica: I tried it out and it seems the documentation is full of lies. It worked when I passed in the result of textToXML to xmlToJSON.

Comment: Thanks, Matti. Switching to an earlier version seemed to help. Also looking at the examples more carefully to see what his JSON comes out like. It's working for me now.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't necessary to switch to the earlier version. The format of the JSON just wasn't what I was expecting. I like the JSON produced by this plugin better: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/, though it doesn't distinguish between values and attributes.